# How do I remove a character from a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I need help debugging my code. I've tried many things, but I can't seem to be able to delete a character from a string.

I also don't understand completely how std::erase works, I'm not sure if you can erase characters with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    string s;
    char n;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0;i < s.length(); i++) {
        s.erase (n[i]);
    }

    cout << s;

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT: Sorry for being so vague. I recognized my issue of attempting to delete something from an array rather than the intended string. With the help of the answers posted; the updated code is attached below that works the way I want it to. Thank you for your responses!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){

string s;
char n;
cin >> s;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    while (s[i] == n) {
      s.erase(i, i);
    }
}

cout << s;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is `n[i]` even supposed to be? It does not make any sense in this code and I don't know what you intended it to become

Comment: It seems you want to remove the character stored in `n` from `s`. Since neither `n` nor `i` is an array, the expression `n[i]` seems to be illegal. The member `erase()` erases the characters from a position and with a given length (up to the end of the string by default). If you, indeed, want to remove instances of `n` from `s` you should have a look at `std::remove()`.

Comment: That code [does not compile](https://ideone.com/3M01b4). Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be helpful if you included a proper description of what you are trying to do. The question is a little vague but I presume you are trying to remove a given char from a string, if that's what you are trying to do, here is a working example that builds on what you already provided.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    string s;
    char n ;

    cin >> s;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == n) {

          s.erase(i, 1);

        }           
    }

    cout << s;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `s.length() - 1` should be `s.length()`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::string s = "Hello World!";
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 'l', s.end());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Broken down into two statements it would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::string s = "Hello World!";
    auto it = std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 'l');
    s.erase(it, s.end());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to remove one character from the string you can use its method `find` to find the character in the string. For example

```
auto pos = s.find( n );
if ( pos != std::string::npos ) s.erase( pos, 1 );
```

Or you can use a loop the following way

```
std::string::size_type pos = 0;

while ( pos < s.size() && s[pos] != n ) ++pos;

if ( pos != s.size() ) s.erase( pos, 1 );
```

If you want to erase all occurrences of the character in the string using a loop you can write

```
for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; pos < s.size(); )
{
    if ( s[pos] == n ) s.erase( pos, 1 );
    else ++pos;
}
```

Comment: Please note that these solutions all have worst-case quadratic complexity! You are much better off using `std:::remove()` in combination with `s.erase()` as this approach has lonear complexity.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I am sure that the author of the question learns how to use loops with strings and the class methods. He knows yet nothing about standard algorithms.